# Completion handler needed for calling data from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

Im trying to call data from firebase. The problem is, the data is deeply nested and I don't think I can change that.

So I'm attempting to call values from firebase, which I can then use to reference new values.
The problem arises when my for loop is not finished before the next stage is called, meaning my dictionary count for the next stage is 0, so my next function is not called?

Is there a way to do this sufficiently?

Please help?

Heres my code:

```
func fetchBuyer(search: String, user: String, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> (), withCancel cancel: ((Error) -> ())?) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user).child(search).child("purchases")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            completion([])
            return
        }

        let keys: [String] = dictionaries.map({ $0.key })
        var newdictionaries = [String: String]()

        for i in keys {
            let newref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user).child(search).child("purchases").child(i).child("purchaser")
            newref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                newdictionaries[i] = snapshot.value as? String
                print("THESE ARE MY PURCHASES ID-->", newdictionaries.values)///prints out ["-M0pTHtZXYUVQT7DCLj-", "-M0pU79uQCCnBunAEkJN"]
            })
        }

        var buyerPosts = [Post]()
        print("newdictionaries.count--->", newdictionaries.count)//this print is 0
        newdictionaries.forEach({ (postId, value) in
            Database.database().fetchPost(withUID: user, postId: postId, completion: { (post) in
                buyerPosts.append(post)
                if buyerPosts.count == newdictionaries.count{
                    completion(buyerPosts)
                }
            })
        })
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch posts for buyers:", err)
        cancel?(err)
    }
}
```

Attempted answer:

```
            let g = DispatchGroup()  //// 1
           for i in keys{
               g.enter()   //// 2
               let newref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user).child(search).child("purchases").child(i).child("purchaser")
            print("now")
            newref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                       newdictionaries[i] = snapshot.value as? String
                        print("print new dictionaries-->", newdictionaries)
                       // complete here
                Database.database().fetchPost(withUID: user, postId: newdictionaries[i]!, completion: { (post) in
                                buyerPosts.append(post)
                                g.leave() //////// 3
                         })
                    })
             }
         g.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            print("finished!!!")
           completion(buyerPosts)
         }
```

Comment: You might be interested in DispatchGroup, `leave()`, `enter()`, `notify()`.

Comment: Now that the code is properly formatted, the code following the `for i in keys` will be called before the data can be returned from Firebase with the closure following `Database.database().fetchPost1`. If you move the code, starting with `var buyerPosts = [Post]()` within the firebase closure, it will work 'better'. However, that's not a solution. To get to a solution we would need to understand your structure and what data you're trying to get at. Also, if you are in development, why can't you change the structure? copy and paste a snippet of your structure using the console->Export JSON and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dispatch group and nest the calls

```
    let g = DispatchGroup()  //// 1

    for i in keys{
        g.enter()   //// 2
        let newref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user).child(search).child("purchases").child(i).child("purchaser")
             newref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) 
                newdictionaries[i] = snapshot.value as? String 
                // complete here 
                    Database.database().fetchPost(withUID: user, postId: postId, completion: { (post) in
                         buyerPosts.append(post)
                         g.leave() //////// 3
                  })

             })
      }

 /// 4
  g.notfiy(queue.main) {
    completion(buyerPosts)
  }
```

Comment: Im getting the error: `Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored` on the line - observeSingleEvent?
See edit.